# Why do I get a ')' expected when I try to get my HTML to work in my Java code?

Tags: java, html, cgi

I was wondering why I cannot find a way to get my frameset (HTML) to work in java. I know I need more code for the frameset, but it keep ending up with the same error.

```
private static void showHead() {
  if ( session == null )
     System.out.println("Set-Cookie: __session="+(int)(Math.random()*100000000));
  System.out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN\">");
  System.out.println("<HTML>");
  System.out.println("<HEAD>");
  System.out.println("<TITLE>The CGIcookie application</TITLE>");
  System.out.println("<META http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\">");
  System.out.println("<META http-equiv=\"Pragma\" content=\"no-cache\">");
  System.out.println("<META http-equiv=\"expires\" content=\"0\">");
  System.out.println("</HEAD>");
  System.out.println("<BODY>");
  System.out.println("<frameset cols"10%,80%">"); //This line gives the error '(' expected
 }

 private static void showTail() {
  System.out.println("</BODY>\n</HTML>");
 }
```

I don't know if you need more of the code to "solve" this. But when I tried to post with the whole code I got a msg that said my post was mostly code and therefore couldn't be submitted.

Comment: Escape the quotes inside the method call argument 

e.g. `System.out.println("<frameset cols\"10%,80%\">");`

Comment: That `frameset` is probably the only line you have written yourself. Just look how all the other lines work: each `"` is preceded by `\ `. Try to imitate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `frameset` tag, you need to escape the quote marks and you are missing an equal sign:

```
System.out.println("<frameset cols=\"10%,80%\">");
```